# How to decrease render distance in GTA San Andreas?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Is there any way to **decrease** render distance in GTA San Andreas?
I browsed on Google and there are tons of mods out there to increase it but none to decrease it. And I want it because GTA SA just runs fine on my laptop but my GPU is now causing problems with render distance (not draw distance), so is there any way to make it like 0.5 or something?

Comment: first of all is it original SA or SA DE?

Comment: Classic og sa it is